# Create a base64 md5 hash in nodejs equivalent to this openssl command

Tags: node.js, openssl

I have a linux command to create argument value, but I dont know how to convert it in nodejs. This is linux command line:

```
echo -n '2147483647/s/link127.0.0.1 secret' | \
openssl md5 -binary | openssl base64 | tr +/ -_ | tr -d =
```

and result when execute it in terminal

```
_e4Nc3iduzkWRm01TBBNYw
```

Please tell me how to make it in nodejs without child process.

Comment: Are you asking how to execute a shell command within javascript (or node.js, I presume from the tag), or are you asking how to convert it to do what that does entirely within javascript?

Comment: Sorry, I mean I want to make a function in node make argument value without execute linux command line (not use child process or something like that).

Comment: oh, well I just answered by using a child process, sorry!

Comment: This looks doable, but as a question it is too broad.  Search [npm](https://www.npmjs.com) for node libraries for md5 and base64.  Perhaps [jshashes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jshashes) would be a good fit since it has both.  `tr` in the shell does character replacement in strings and could be re-Implemented  with a few string replace calls.   After you've added an appropriate library and written some code, and then are confused, ask another question.

Comment: Thanks Brian, Paul.
@Paul : Can you say more about this?

Comment: echo -n "something" is only a string.  openssl md5 is very likely the same md5() function in jshashes and emits a binary output.  base64 is a function that takes that binary data and encodes it as a string and it is also probably in jshashes... The first tr changes characters in the string output by base64.  The second tr deletes the `=` symbol from the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done

```
 var mysecretkey = "secret";
    var path = "/s/link";
    var ip = '127.0.0.1';
    var time = '2147483647';
    var path = time + path + ip + ' ' + mysecretkey;
    var crypto = require('crypto');
    var md5sum = crypto.createHash('md5');
    var d = md5sum.update(path).digest('base64');
    //#echo -n '2147483647/s/link127.0.0.1 secret' | openssl md5 -binary | openssl base64 | tr +/ -_ | tr -d =
    var test = d.replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/=/g, '');
    console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

Any terminal command can be executed in Node.js by using the exec or spawn.  In this case, exec will probably be your best bet.  Follow the pattern below just replace my command to list the directories in /home/username with whatever command you want:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec("ls /home/username", function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log("error: ", error);
    console.log("stdout: ", stdout);
    console.log("stderr: ", stderr);
});
```

Comment: But when I wanto execute in windows platform, I think it will not working.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback, the specific command will need to conform to whatever OS you are working on, but exec is platform independent

Comment: But I think openssl md5 -binary | openssl base64 not available on  windows.